# Need to edit a photo and draw mathematical writin and physical schematic forces on a diagram of a aerial robotic system

Tags: diagrams, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing

How are you?

I'm a grad student and I need to do a mathematical and physical model a quadcopter robotic system . I've found a web site with a picture that looks like a lot to what I have to do: I have to take a picture of the robotic system i've built (it's not that in the picture but is similar) and draw and show all the forces and measures that this picure have. I know this is a TEX sub and not a photo editing one but maybe someone could point me out a way to find this kind of information.

What program can I use to do all these things? Could someone point me some tutorial or where to find orientation for that?

PS: I'm citing the article in my research ;)
https://charlestytler.com/quadcopter-equations-motion/

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Try Inkscape (OpenSource) or CorelDraw (commercial). It can be done with Tikz, but you have to import the image anyway, so it is really not worth the effort

Comment: You might find this question helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/86